# Scrapy: render a different html

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrap the table of this webpage (https://www.ftse.com/products/indices/uk). When I try to fetch the data in the shell for a quick test it seems to work fine but when I view the response, the browser open the following link: file:///private/var/folders/8z/pwlxvfrj4zz3vqbpddc357lr0000gn/T/tmpvcqkek5z.html. This link contains some layout elements of the original one but it misses all the data. What could be the reason of this discrepancies?

Comment: Did you send a proper value for 'User-Agent' within your request headers? If not the server might decide that it's not gonna deliver the complete site but just a notice about breaking the TOS.

Comment: No. I am new to scrapy and to crawl website in general but I have tried many examples before to get up to speed and this never happened. I will try to follow your suggestion and let you know. Thx!

Comment: I have tried to change manually the default user agent with the following command: scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36" 'https://www.ftse.com/products/indices/uk'.    but the response I get is still incomplete

Comment: Well, in that case you could try and send a cookie along with the request ... or maybe just use another source page that isn't such a pain to scrap.